# Design grid of RFID readers with possible stacked tags

Tags: rfid

I want to get a grid of RFID readers in rather close proximity (cells should be around 45mm x 45mm -- could increase a bit if necessary). I also want to be able to detect up to at least 3 stacked tags per cell (each tag will be about 10mm). I understand that this is rather challenging because of interference all over the place.

I started researching if this is possible. As far as I understand, its not impossible but I might need to keep the active readers neighbors silent while its reading.

Also ISO-15693 allows for stacked tags so it should be doable.

So my background is in Electronic and Electrical Engineering but I have never used it since university (pivoted to computing) so I don't think I am capable doing something too advanced in regards to RF circuit design.

I read that I could do some resonant circuit techniques instead of RFID, but I think it would be challenging when stacking multiple tags.

I was trying to figure out what the best design choices would be for this project. The grid will probably end up being around 156 cells (12x13) or so and buying off the shelf RFID readers can be quiet costly, especially for a non working design.

Do you think this is feasible? And what frequency do you think would be most suitable for such a project? If you have any suggestions regarding the component please let me know.

Comment: Realistically you are asking for opinions because there's no fixed way to approach this as far as I can see and, site rules on this subject say: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: You might want to investigate UHF rfid. You can have a roll of 200 tags and you can read them all. It is unclear the role of the cells - do you want to identify the location of a given tag within a cell? If so, that is a significant challenge for hf and uhf rfid. Sounds like you’d need some method of beam forming to resolve the position. This is not trivial. It would mean you would only need one reader but multiple antennas. Try to distill  the problem down to something simple.